# jquery's .click() doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

when there is

```
<a href="javascript:onclick:alert('hi')"> click </a>.
```

how come `$('a').click();` doesn't make the alert popup?

Comment: i need to literally "click" an element. for instance i did this $('a').trigger('click'); <a href="google.com">; clickme</a> Nothing happened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('hi')"> click </a>
```

Then, to trigger it manually:

```
$('a').trigger('click');
```

Comment: yes. how come it didn't work for me ?

also when there actually is an href URL, why doesn't .trigger('click') make the browser navigate ?

Comment: Why can't you attach the event handler externally, as shown in yoda's and my answers? Inline event handlers are not recommended.

Comment: meder, i need to literally "click" an element.

for instance i did this

$('a').trigger('click');

<a href="http://google.com"> clickme</a>

Nothing happened....

Answer (score 4):

Wether you use normal javascript in the anchor or use jquery. If you want to use jquery, do this :

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   alert('hi');
});
```

.. and remove the code you have inside href="" to something else, like a href="#"

Comment: This won't fix the double click for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because you're not attaching the click event properly, you're hacking it in by throwing it inside the href value. Make it link to # or the real url, don't ever place JS inline. Then attach the event handler externally:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    alert('hi')'
});
```

Then trigger with `.trigger('click')` if you need to do it manually.

Comment: Are you referring to onclick also?  What's wrong with onclick?

Comment: It's an inline event handler and it's a best practice to separate content from presentation, from behavior ( 3 legged stool of web design ).

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you can't trigger the click event is that you are not setting any click event.

The `onclick:` that you have in the code has nothing to do with the `onclick` event, it's just a label. Naming it the same as an event doesn't make anything special happen.

So, your code is equivalent to:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hi')"> click </a>
```

If you want an event, you use the onclick attribute:

```
<a href="somepage.html" onclick="alert('hi');"> click </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to make the click trigger work with href. You have to bind a window.location call using the event target to the click event. This will cause any onclick actions to be triggered, followed by the href target. Like so:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
    window.location = event.target.href;
});

$("a").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your href code. There are two ways to make a link call a javascript function when a user clicks on it:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hi');">click</a>
<a href="" onclick="alert('hi');">click</a>
```

Now you can use the jquery code to click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

There are cases which you can't move the action from `href` to `onclick`. (like ASP.NET post back link buttons)
I wrote the `href` action aware function below to trigger click in such cases:

```
function triggerClickEvent(element) {
    var e = $(element).click();
    if (e.attr('href').indexOf('javascript:') === 0)
        eval(e.attr('href').replace('javascript:', ''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solution to this problem was importing JQuery via http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js link rather than having it on my localhost. I am using Kohana and that strangely did the magic.